# Can not calling get() on pathos apipe() result lead to excessive memory usage?

Tags: pathos

If you use a pathos ThreadPool and call apipe() a large number of times, but never call get() on the result, does this possibly lead to pathos internally accumulating state (and thus using up memory)?

Comment: You mean like does it keep filling up a results queue?

Comment: Can you add some code to show to show exactly what you are doing? For example, are you deleting the returned ApplyResult objects? Which version of python, pathos, etc are you using?  The ApplyResult object points back to the pool or to a threading event or otherwise, depending on the version of python, etc.

Comment: Our app is creating a task pool like this:  task_pool = ThreadPool(24).  Later, various places in the code start tasks like this:  task_pool.apipe(...).  The docs say  apipe returns a result  and one can call get() on this object to get the result. This makes me think pathos must be "remembering" the result of the task so that get() can retrieve it later. So will ten million calls to apipe, with no get(), cause pathos to internally remember all the associated results, which it might otherwise delete if get() were being called?

Answer (score 0):

Without details on the version of python, pathos, etc you are interested in... I can give you a general answer. Calling `apipe` from a `ThreadPool` instance generates a `ApplyResult` object.  Calling `get()` on the instance of an `ApplyResult` object will return the result corresponding to the inputs to `apipe` being evaluated.  So, what happens before you call `get`? The exact details depend on the version of python and pathos, but generally, when you call `apipe`, an `ApplyResult` instance is generated, and the evaluation of the inputs to `apipe` are dispatched to a new thread. The `ApplyResult` instance has a pointer either back to the pool, to a queue, or to some other object that will 'receive the result' when `get` is called. The evaluated result produced in the new thread is stored in memory until get is called... or until the object that holds the result is deallocated from memory (however that happens).  This memory storage most likely happens in an object in the `threading` module... but it may be elsewhere, depending on the version of python, pathos, etc.  Were you to delete the appropriate object, and dealloc it from memory, then you'd never need to call `get` to release the memory.  However, the short answer is "likely yes", not calling `get` will fill up your memory unless the result, the return object, and/or other objects with pointer refs to the result are deleted.